# MapReduce to Spark

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-spark

I have a MapReduce job written in Java. It depends on multiple classes. I want to run the MapReduce job on Spark.

What steps should I follow to do the same?

I need to make changes only to the MapReduce class?

Thanks!

Comment: Start by reading over this blog post: http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/09/how-to-translate-from-mapreduce-to-apache-spark/

Comment: Thanks @JeremyBeard. That was the first article I read when I started this. I updated my question. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very broad question, but the short of it is:

1. Create an RDD of the input data.
2. Call `map` with your mapper code. Output key-value pairs.
3. Call `reduceByKey` with your reducer code.
4. Write the resulting RDD to disk.

Spark is more flexible than MapReduce: there is a great variety of methods that you could use between steps 1 and 4 to transform the data.